# React-Native Navigation without render command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uinavigationcontroller, react-native

Is there anyway to redirect user to a different component (also passing arguments with it) without calling render function?

almost in all tutorials i found, they use sameway :

```
render() {
return (
  <NavigatorIOS
    style={styles.container}
    initialRoute=\{\{
      title: 'first',
      component: First
    }} />
);
```

}

Now see my code :
in renderRow , for touchablehighlights , i need to be able to redirect user to a page with an argument, (in this case i need to send user to component CourseDetail with argument of course_id, so i can show user course's details)

```js
class Courses extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
          }),
          loaded: false,
        };
    }

  fetchData() {
    // fetching data here
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render(){
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1
      }}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderRow(data) {

    var header = (
      <View>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{data.nid}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={0}>{data.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator}></View>
    </View>
    );
///////////
    var cid = [];
    var content = [];
    for(let x=0; x < Object.keys(data.course).length; x++){
      cid[x] = data.course[x].course_id;
      content.push(
        <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor='#e3e0d7'
        key={x}
        onPress={()=>{console.log(cid[x]);}} //// i need to navigate user to a page with passing arguments (course_id in this case)
        style={styles.child}
        >
        <Text style={styles.child}>
        {data.course[x].title}
        </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
    console.log(cid);
    var clist = (
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      {content}
      </View>
    );
////////////
    return (
      <Accordion
        header={header}
        content={clist}
        easing="easeOutCubic"
      />
    );
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loading}>
        <Text style={styles.loading}>
          Loading Courses, please wait...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Courses;
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you tried `this.props.navigator.push({ component: Component })` in the onPress function with component being the component you want to push?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see it in few tutorials but i wasnt sure if it will work for me, also since i'm newbie in react native, i didn't know how exactly to use it. i would really appreciate it if you could give me simple usage example of it. because in tutorials i have found they are to complicated

Comment: i tried navigator.push but it gives error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null(…)

am i missing something? @NaderDabit

Comment: i also tried this but didnt work : 
class Courses extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
          }),
          loaded: false,
        };
        this.rowPress = this.rowPress.bind(this);
    }
rowPress() {
    this.refs.nav.push({
          component: Profile,
          title: 'Profile'
    });

then i called the function on press like this :
onPress={this.rowPress}

Comment: it gives error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowPress' of null
@NaderDabit

Comment: It looks like this is being lost in the context of your function somehow. Maybe set up a separate navigate function something like `navigate (data) { this.props.navigator.push({ component: someComponent, passProps: { data: data } }) } ` then call it like this: `onPress={this.navigate.bind(this, data)}`

Comment: If you can recreate a basic version with dummy data at https://rnplay.org/ it would be really helpful.

Comment: @NaderDabit  , sorry for late answer and thanks for your reply. i wasnt able to add new files in rnplay, i dont know how to do that, so i have copied code from only the file i have problem in here https://rnplay.org/apps/wkf7Aw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By help of this Question here :
[React-Native: Cannot access state values or any methods declared from renderRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262837/react-native-cannot-access-state-values-or-any-methods-declared-from-renderrow)

I was able to solve the issue by changing :

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow}
    style={styles.listView}
  />
```

To :

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
    style={styles.listView}
  />
```

Hope it will help others who may have the same problem.