# React-Native: Cannot access state values or any methods declared from renderRow

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, uinavigationcontroller, react-native

I have a listview, whenever user clicks on an item, i want to do something with onPress (touchable highlight).

I tried defining function then calling them in onPress but they didnt work.

first i defined a function like this :

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
          }),
          loaded: false,
        };
        this._dosome = this._dosome.bind(this);
    }

    _dosome(dd){
      console.log(dd);
    }
```

Then :

```
render(){
  if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1
      }}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderRow(data) {

    var header = (
      <View>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{data.nid}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={0}>{data.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator}></View>
    </View>
    );
///////////
    var cid = [];
    var content = [];
    for(let x=0; x < Object.keys(data.course).length; x++){
      cid[x] = data.course[x].course_id;
      content.push(
        <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor='#e3e0d7'
        key={x}
        onPress={ this._dosome } //// **** PROBLEM HERE ****
        style={styles.child}
        >
        <Text style={styles.child}>
        {data.course[x].title}
        </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
    console.log(cid);
    var clist = (
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      {content}
      </View>
    );
////////////
    return (
      <Accordion
        header={header}
        content={clist}
        easing="easeOutCubic"
      />
    );
  }


  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loading}>
        <Text style={styles.loading}>
          Loading Courses, please wait...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But it didnt worked, error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_dosome' of null(…)
```

I tried calling it onPress like this :

```
onPress={ this._dosome.bind(this) }
```

didn't help

```
onPress={ ()=> {this._dosome.bind(this)}}
```

didn't help

```
onPress={ console.log(this.state.loaded)}
```

even i cannot even access props defined in constructor. it don't know what is "this" !

I tried to define the function other way like this :

```
var _dosome = (dd) => {
      console.log(dd);
    };
```

I tried defining the _dosome before render, after render, inside render, inside renderRow, and after renderRow. all same results.

I did check lots of tutorials, lots of sample apps on rnplay, lots of threads in stackoverflow, lots of examples, but none of them worked for me.
any solutions/ideas?
Any help is highly appreciated. i'm struggling with this issue for 2 days now.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please tell us your version of react-native

Comment: @DavidGuan , i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: You can check it in your `package.json`, something like "react-native": "0.29.0"

Comment: I'm so sorry, i misread your question. it's 0.27.2

Comment: Thanks a lot. already solved by your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### How to solve your problem

Change

```
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow}
    style={styles.listView}
  />
```

To

```
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={data => this.renderRow(data)}
    style={styles.listView}
  />
```

Or

```
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
    style={styles.listView}
  />
```

### Why?

As you already know(since you are trying to solve the problem by using arrow function and `bind`), to call `renderRow`, the caller should be in the same context as the component itself.
But this connection is lost in `renderRow={this.renderRow}`, which created a new function(new context).